# Performance of Nested ElaasticSearch Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, inverted-index

I was working on a project that needs to index a bunch of Products and their Variants into ElasticSearch. Variants have the same schema as Products in DB. So naturally, I started with designing a mapping that is exactly the same as the Product schema and index products and variants as their own documents.

But later, when I accidentally tried to index variants as nested objects inside products, the indexing process is 3x-5x faster (tested several times locally with 1000 products&5 variants, 2000 products&10 variants, and 25000 products&5 variants). The mapping looks something like the below:

```
id: keyword
name: text
sku: keyword
price: long
color: keyword
...
variants: [
  {
    id: keyword
    name: text
    sku: keyword
    price: long
    color: keyword
    ...
  }
]
```

So the question is why is that. Since the data size would be the same, a nested mapping will cause a longer index time due to 2x fields. Also, I'm using `_bulk` API to index products with their variants in each API call, so the request count would be the same.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on why is this.

PS: I'm running ElasticSearch 6.7 locally

Comment: You meant ,But later, when I accidentally tried to index variants as nested objects inside products, the index time is 3x-5x **faster**, slower here in this para, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Amit Thanks for your comment, but I think I'm correct there, the index time for the nested documents is shorter and the question is why. Cause intuitively it should take longer to index larger documents

Comment: ok, might be this is due to localization, index time might be better but search would be definitely costly on the nested fields, would suggest you to benchmark that as well..

Comment: @Amit Yea, that is definitely a valid assumption. In fact, I'm working on a load testing script later today and will do a query time comparison tmr.

Comment: cool, waiting for your results, it would be interesting to see results, btw you can use the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html for search queries, but As far as I know it doesn't exist for indexing queries

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to answer the question, "why indexing time is different."

Nested documents are indexed differently. Internally nested documents are indexed as separate documents - but indexed as a single block within Lucene.

Suppose your document contains two variants in the nested data structure. In that case, the total number of documents indexed will be 3 ( 1 parent doc + 2 variants as separate docs) - internally [by](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocuments-java.lang.Iterable-)  `.[addDocuments()][1]`  Lucene call. This guarantees documents are indexed in a single block and available to query using nested query ( nested query joins these documents in runtime).

This results in a different indexing behavior. In your case - it got faster, but say if you have thousands of variants per product, too many nested structures can give you indexing problems. There are [some limits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html#) to avoid it.